# Convert Array suitable for CI dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I'm using a CodeIgniter method (db->result_array()) that returns me the following array:

```
 Array
 (
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 5
        [lang_name] => ASM
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 16
        [lang_name] => Bash
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 17
        [lang_name] => Batch
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [lang_name] => C
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 11
        [lang_name] => C#
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 4
        [lang_name] => C++
    )
 )
```

And i need an array with this format, to pass it to the form_dropdown() CI function:

```
 $atrLangDropDown = array(
    '1' => 'CPP',
    '2' => 'PHP',
    '3' => 'ASM'
);
```

I've done something like this:

```
public function getAllLangsSelect() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from($this->tableName)->order_by($this->tableName.'.lang_name');
    $q = $this->db->get();
    $data = array();
    array_push($data, '- Select Language -');

    foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) {  
        array_push($data, $row['lang_name']);
    }

    return $data;

}
```

But it musts conserve the original ID stored in the DataBase, so it doesn't work as it should.

Any hint or help will be welcome. It's the first time when i do this kind of operations.

Comment: I just done it, thanks by the way.

The solution is:

     public function getAllLangsSelect() {
  $this->db->select('*')->from($this->tableName)->order_by($this->tableName.'.lang_name');
  $q = $this->db->get();
  $data = array();

  $tmp = $q->result_array();
  
  for ($i = 0; $i < count ($tmp); $i++) {
   echo $tmp[$i]['id']." - ".$tmp[$i]['lang_name']."<br />";
   $x = $tmp[$i]['id'];
   $data[$x] = $tmp[$i]['lang_name'];
  }
  
  //print_r($data);
  return $data;
  
 }

Hope can be usefull to someone.

Comment: I missed your comment while posting, but in the future you are welcome to answer your own question, as well as accept the answer you provided. Unformatted blobs of code don't usually belong in the comments, they are impossible to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function getAllLangsSelect()
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->order_by('lang_name')
        ->get($this->tableName);

    $options[''] = '- Select Language -';

    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
    {  
        $options[$row->id] = $row->lang_name;
    }

    return $options;
}
```